# PHP file uploading file error

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a image file using php. I'm using a simple file uploading code like on www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, however sometimes the php file fails to upload the images,

The images are not that large. One is just 130kb in size, the uploading process goes up to 48% fine, then slows down reaches 72% after a long time and gives me an error "Incomplete request". Is there any way to fix this thanks.

**Edit**

Code :

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? It's kind of hard to see this way. Usually this is caused with configuration issues on the server. However, you seem to be mentioning that some file **do** in fact get uploaded, correct?

Comment: @Digitalis code posted, yes some of the photos do get uploaded, some don't, they are downloaded from the internet, i tried the same images on gmail and gmail uploads the images fine, but having the same issues on tumblr

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error on my dev-server I'm afraid. The best of luck, but I wouldn't know the answer.

Comment: If it's always the same (collection of...) file(s) that don't upload, you should add an example of one of these files, at least the complete name.

Comment: Is your server low on disk space?

Comment: how are you measuring the percent completion of the uploading process?

Comment: Maybe you have a file size limit in your `php.ini` file. I had it when I started working with files...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try first

```
$foo = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$extension = end($foo);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                   "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Then:

- Increase the of the images to uploaded
- Then inside your file where all contents are located, create folder with where you want your pictures to be stored, the folder should be named `upload`